# Making a survey app, how should I delete questions (and add some layout)?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm making a survey app using a Survey model, which has_many Questions which itself has_many answers. The form partial looks like this:

```
<%= form_for(@survey) do |f| %>
  <% if @survey.errors.any? %>
    <div id="error_explanation">
      <h2><%= pluralize(@survey.errors.count, "error") %> prohibited this survey from being saved:</h2>

      <ul>
      <% @survey.errors.full_messages.each do |message| %>
        <li><%= message %></li>
      <% end %>
      </ul>
    </div>
  <% end %>


  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :name %><br>
    <%= f.text_field :name %>
  </div>

  <%= f.fields_for :questions do |question_attribute| %>
  <p>
    <%= question_attribute.label :content, "Question" %><br />
    <%= question_attribute.text_area :content, :rows => 3 %>
  </p>

   <%= question_attribute.fields_for :answers do |answer_attribute| %>
    <p>
      <%= answer_attribute.label :content, "Answer" %>
      <%= answer_attribute.text_field :content %>

    </p>
   <% end %> 
 <% end %> 



  <div class="actions">
    <%= f.submit %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

and is called by the edit and new actions. **quick side note: how is it that rails fills in previous question/answer values in the form when called by the edit action?**

I want to make it so that when I visit each survey's edit page, beside each question will be a "delete" link, and when I press that delete link the question is deleted from the survey and I'm directed back to the edit page. How should I accomplish this? I took a look at some railscasts but everything they did had been deprecated already.

In addition, right now when I `show` a survey, the questions aren't numbered ie Question 2, Question 2, etc. and the Answers for each question aren't numbered a), b), c), d), e). How do I make rails automatically number these when I create a survey? My show form looks like this:

```
<p id="notice"><%= notice %></p>

<p>
  <strong>Name:</strong>
  <%= @survey.name %>
</p>

<ol>
  <% @survey.questions.each do |question| %>
  <li><%= question.content  %>
  <ul>
    <% for answer in question.answers %>

    <li><%= answer.content %></li>

    <% end %>
  </ul>
  </li>
    <% end %>
</ol>


<%= link_to 'Edit', edit_survey_path(@survey) %> |
<%= link_to 'Back', surveys_path %>
```

Comment: Your side note: I'll use the new action as an example. When you go to create a new object with the form_for helper the new action will pass it survey = Survey.new. But if your validations fails during the create action and re-renders new, it is now using the survey = Survey.new(params) object and form_for is smart enough to auto fill the fields that aren't empty from the params.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I've actually figured out how to delete questions now  -- do you know how I would number my Questions and number my answers?